# Ruby Telegram Bot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, telegram-bot

I want to get the Telegram Bout to withdraw an custom information out of Telegram.

```
when "/invite (xyz)"
  bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Inviting (xyz)")
```

the bot should withdraw me the (xyz) to the coustom message.
the other think is, how can i let ruby paste me the coustom name into a text file, with an command line "/invite (xyz)" <--- into the text file.
so if i do at telegram: /invite Rob

Telegram should write me "Inviting Rob" and print me into the text file "/invite Rob"

Is there any way to take out the custom (xyz) word and read it out and use it in the code?

Comment: I think you are talking about regular expressions in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
if text_field.start_with? '/invite '
  bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Inviting #{text_field.sub('/invite ',''}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case message

when Telegram::Bot::Types::Message

    if message.text.start_with?('/start')

        ...

    elsif message.text.start_with?('/help')

        ...

    else

        ...

    end

end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[answer]" and its linked pages along with "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
and "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)". See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex:

```rb
case str
when /\/invite (.*)/
  bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Inviting #{Regexp.last_match[1]}")
  File.open('your_file.txt', 'a') { |f| f.puts(Regexp.last_match) }
when /\/greet (.*)/
  # ...
end
```